# In how many ways can arrange $3$ balls of vanilla, $4$ balls of chocolate, and $3$ balls of strawberry ice cream be arranged with restrictions?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> 3 balls of vanilla ice cream, 4 balls of chocolate ice cream and 3 balls of strawberry ice cream should be arranged in 6 different bowls . No dish may contain three balls of the same flavor. In how many different ways can this be achieved if is there one ball of vanilla, there must be at least a ball of chocolate and if is there at least one ball of chocolate there must be at least one ball of strawberry?

I figured that second part will maybe be 6*5*(6+4*3) but i am confused in explanation of full result.

[this is answer of my college, still confused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gupGl.jpg)

Thank you very much...

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, you should include your own attempt to solve the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: Are the bowls themselves considered distinct?  Can bowls be empty?  (I sure hope so, since otherwise you can only make fill three bowls since everyone wants strawberry).

Comment: sorry, it isnt 8 bowls , its 6 bowls.

Comment: Regardless, there can be at most three bowls which receive icecream at all since everyone who gets any ice cream must have strawberry included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the bowls are distinct and bowls may be empty:

Let us approach via quite tedious case-work.

Notice that anyone who has chocolate must also have strawberry.  Notice further that anyone who has vanilla must have chocolate, which by the previous sentence implies that they also have strawberry.  This implies that *everyone* who has any icecream at all will have strawberry.

Pick how to distribute the strawberry icecream.

- Case 1: Someone gets all three scoops of strawberry.  This is not allowed, as per the rule that nobody gets three of the same flavor.
- Case 2: Someone gets two scoops of strawberry and another person gets one.  ($6\cdot 5$ ways: *note, we can tell the difference between the person who gets two scoops and the person who gets one scoop, so we may choose them separately*)
- Case 3: Three people get one scoop of strawberry each.  ($\binom{6}{3}$ ways: *note, we cannot tell ahead of time the difference between the people who get one scoop so we must choose them simultaneously*)

Whichever is chosen, from there, decide how to distribute the chocolate icecream to those people who already have strawberry icecream.

- Case 2a: Of the two people who got strawberry icecream, one gets two scoops of chocolate and the other also gets two scoops of chocolate ($1$ way)
- Case 2b: Of the two people who got strawberry icecream, one gets three and the other gets one.  Impossible as per the rule that noone gets three of a flavor.
- Case 2c: Of the two people who got strawberry icecream, one gets four and the other gets none.  Presumably impossible assuming that the phrase "no bowl may contain three of the same flavor" also prevents a bowl from having more than three of the same flavor.  Otherwise, two possibilities.
- Case 3a: Of the three people who got strawberry icecream, two people get two each.  $\binom{3}{2}$ ways.
- Case 3b: Of the three people who got strawberry icecream, one person gets two scoops and two people get one scoop each. $\binom{3}{2}$ ways.
- Case 3c: A person gets three and another gets one, or a person gets four.  Both are impossible.

Whichever is chosen, from there, decide how to distribute the vanilla icecream.  These must be distributed to the people who already have some chocolate, keeping in mind that the people with the same current amount of icecream totals are difficult to tell apart.

- Case 2aA: The person with two scoops of strawberry gets two scoops of vanilla
- Case 2aB: The person with two scoops of strawberry gets one scoop of vanilla
- Case 3aA: Of the two people who got chocolate, pick one of them to get two scoops of vanilla:  $2$ choices
- Case 3bA: The person with two scoops of chocolate gets two scoops of vanilla.  Pick one of the people who got one scoop of chocolate to get the remaining scoop of vanilla: $2$ choices
- Case 3bB: A person who got one scoop of chocolate gets two scoops of vanilla.  Pick a remaining person with chocolate to get the remaining scoop of vanilla.  $4$ choices
- Case 3bC: All three people with chocolate get a scoop of vanilla each: $1$ choice.

Tally all choices together for a final answer.

By my count, $2\cdot 6\cdot 5 + (7\cdot 3+2\cdot 3)\cdot \binom{6}{3} = 600$ different ways.

This agrees with the answer of $\binom{6}{3}\cdot 3 + 6\cdot 5(6+4\cdot 3)=600$ shown in your linked image.  It appears that their answer began with distributing the vanilla icecream first, whereas I began my answer by distributing the strawberry first.

---

The apparent logic behind the pictured answer:

The vanilla will either be in one batch of two scoops and one batch of one scoop, or in three batches of one scoop.  Whichever occurs, we must include with it a minimum of one scoop of chocolate and one scoop of vanilla, so include those simultaneously.

If all vanilla was in separate bowls, that implies all strawberry must be in those bowls as well, implying that one of these must have two chocolate.  Pick which bowl has $1$ vanilla, $2$ chocolate, and $1$ strawberry, and which two bowls have $1$ vanilla, $1$ chocolate, and $1$ strawberry.  This contributes $\binom{6}{3}\cdot 3$ to the total sum.

If there was a bowl with two vanilla in it, place $2$ vanilla, $1$ chocolate, $1$ strawberry in a bowl, and $1$ vanilla, $1$ chocolate, and $1$ strawberry in another.  We still have yet to place the remaining $2$ choclate and $1$ strawberry.  Break into cases based on how to do this.

Comment: Beautiful community here. Thank you very much kind sir.

Comment: Thank you very much for effort. I find this very complicated and hard in my opinion, especially because of long explanations.

Answer (score 1):

If you should put at least one ball in each bowl, there is no solution.

You must use a ball of vanilla. In any bowl you place, you have to add a chocolate and a strawberry too. For the remaining 7 bowls, you have 7 balls of ice cream, from which 3 is chocolate.

Try to see why it is not possible to fill all bowls!

Comment: If you can leave a bowl empty and they are distinguished, I would recommend to switch cases depending on in how many different bowls you put the three bowls of vanilla, and after count, with the same switching method, how many different ways you can place the chocolate and strawberry balls, but pay attention that since you have less strawberry than chocolate, there must be a bowl with two balls of chocolate.

Comment: sorry for my bad english, but you dont need to use vanilla in all bowls, i edited, it says if is there, anywhere, one ball of vanilla then u must have at least one chocolade and so on..

Comment: [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gupGl.jpg) should this will be answer?

Comment: It still holds that you cannot fill all the 6 bowls, since if you may put
-vanilla you have to put chocolate and so strawberry
-chocolate, you have to put strawberry too
-strawberry
You can see that in each case the bowl must contain strawberry, so since you have only 3 strawberry balls, it's not possible to fill all the bowls.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more your attempt?

Comment: This kinds of problems we get at final exam and allways they get so complicated so its really hard to translate to english. I tried to solve, but nothing worth of posting. I only have this answer from my college, that i posted before in link.